# how to get rails app to pull data from api without user starting up server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a local rails app that calls to an api from the model. It then saves the data from the api into a database. In controller#index it calls all the data that was saved and in the view it displays the results of the index action. The call to the api currently is dependent on a user going to local host and triggering the model. How do I get it so that the function within the app can make timed calls to the api without a user triggering it? Also how would I do this after deployment in heroku?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gem whenever`

https://github.com/javan/whenever

It uses crontab for running regular tasks.

You can make some class, or rake task, that will pull data from api and save in db.